# Using a php file to redirect from port 80 to another port

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I need to make a http call from Javascript to my web client which is port 7043. So I m making a php call that will redirect my call. My php and javascript files are in the root directory of apache and my javascript is making the call to the php file (http://localhost/redirect.php) and this is what I am doing in the php file

```
$file = fsockopen("localhost:7043/test/testclient.json", 7043)
```

This does seem to only open the initial "It works!" web page that comes with apache. the testclient.json returns a json response (which I parse in Javascript) could this be the problem? what do I need to do in php?

Comment: cant u use .htaccess code instead ?

Comment: im not familiar with this. could you elaborate?

Comment: Is it webclient or server at port 7043 ?

Comment: Can you use jQuery? Or is it forbidden on your server?

Comment: server is in port 7043

Comment: jQuery (from your Javascript file) has an easy solution to that case. Unless you have to elaborate more on your very problem.

Comment: Port 7043 is public-facing?

Comment: @DanielBeauyat I am not sure how to do it in jquery. Could you help me out with an example? any documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

You have to write only:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost:7043/test/testclient.json?callback=jp", function(jsonRecieved){
  // jsonReceived is a var that contains your testclient.json already parsed by jQuery
  // so, do what you want with it here
});
```

In your **html body**, put somewhere (before `</body>` for example)

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

You can download jQuery and see more at https://jquery.com/ 
See some [$.getJSON examples](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). 
More about [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

Comment: .getJson would go in the javascript file right? I am pretty new to this so just wondering. And thanks I will try this out

Comment: Yes! That code is for your JS file. Note that JS is **case sensitive**; so ".getJson" is not the right call - you'd write `$.getJSON`

Comment: For accurate help, you could show relevant parts of your source code (js file, PHP/html body)

Comment: I just ran the code you said and it gives me the error XMLHTTPRequest cannot load http://localhost:7043/test/testclient.json No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Enable CORS on your server. If your server is Apache, you may use .htacess file to enable CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) like this demo ([link](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)). If your JSON file is generated by PHP, then add `<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); ?>` at the top of your PHP file. _Before that try again using the modified URL in $.getJSON (updated answer)_